# Wrap Panel is not wrapping DataItems

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit, wrappanel

I have WrapPanel where I want the control inside of it to go horizontally and centered, but when I have a listbox or a ItemsControl those elements just go downwards.

```
<toolkit:WrapPanel>

    <ItemsControl x:Name="AnswerListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- those don't wrap horizontally and go downwards -->
                <local:spriteToggleButton Text="{Binding text}" Selected="{Binding selected}" Sprites="{Binding Path=DataContext.UISprites, ElementName=questionField}" IsChecked="{Binding selected, Mode=TwoWay}" GroupName="{Binding Path=DataContext.QuestionTitle, ElementName=questionField}" ClickMode="Press" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

</toolkit:WrapPanel>
```

I came across some similar issues and found out about ItemsPanel, so I tried that but it wrap but only to Content and didn't display the rest of the control inside of it.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <toolkit:WrapPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

I take it that ItemsPanel is telling the ItemsControl which control to wrap it with but then it seems to ignore the rest of my datatemplate.

Answer (score 1):

Joseph,

Slightly shooting in the dark here; but this is how I have used the WrapPanel (not through the ItemControl).

```
<ListBox> 
   <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <toolkit:WrapPanel Width="700" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
         ....
         </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Essentially the Listbox's ItemsPanel tells it to use the WrapPanel and then you could have anything you need in the DataTemplate. Note that the width is important as it tells the WrapPanel where to start wrapping.

Does this help?

Comment: it still does the same thing, only the content is present in the custom control, but it does go horizontally

Comment: the dependency properties aren't being changed, xxDependencyPropertyValueChanged does not run because the DataContext is being lost somehow or the binding for that property is not changing it.